# Move up and move down row of a HTML table

Tags: jquery, html

There is a table where user can select multiple rows, In selected rows,I need to set a value 0 (Zero) if there is any text box (which is inside ) which has class "weight"

Below is my JQuery code

```
var tr = $(".selectRow")
$(tr).each(function() { 
    $(this).find("td.weight").val(0);   
});
```

but it is not working, any suggestion please ?

Comment: there is no value attribute in td tag since you said text box,
maybe you mean $(this).find("td.weight input[type='text']").val("0") ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
var tr = $(".selectRow")
$(tr).each(function() { 
    $(this).find(".weight").val(0);   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(".selectRow .weight input").val(0);
```

This would set the values of all the input textboxes (inside your `.weight` cells) to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting the td element and not the text box inside it. just add the "input" to your selector.

```
var tr = $(".selectRow")
            $(tr).each(function() { 
                $(this).find("td input.weight").val(0);   
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a causal look at that code suggests you need to iterate the td as it expects any number of tds otherwise use first()

```
  var tr = $(".selectRow")
        $(tr).each(function() { 
            $(this).first("td.weight").val(0);   
        });
```

Comment: one more thing $(this).first("td.weight input")